# Spring MVC - Charset breaking when I submit my form

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

**SOLUTION:** I've changed the server from tomcat to jetty and the charset is back to normal

I'm having some trouble with the enconding on a application. Everytime I save something to the database the encoding breaks, but for reading is ok (I tested by changing manually on the db).

As Ralph asked I've checked if the charset is broke before I save on the database, and it's. So I'm changing the question to reflect better the problem.

I'm using Spring MVC, Hibernate and MySQL. I've configurated spring to use UTF-8 in my configuration class:

```
public class ServletSpringMVC extends     AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { AppWebConfiguration.class, JPAConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter encodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        encodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[] {encodingFilter};
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(""));
    }


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException             {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(RequestContextListener.class);
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
    }

}
```

My JSP is:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<tags:template title="Jobs">
<jsp:attribute name="bodyArea">

<div class="container">
    <c:if test="${not empty jobId}">
        <c:url var="urlAction" value="${spring:mvcUrl('JC#updateJob').arg(0,jobId).build()}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${empty jobId}">
        <c:url var="urlAction" value="${spring:mvcUrl('JC#addJob').build()}"/>
    </c:if>
    <form:form action="${urlAction}" method="post" modelAttribute="jobDTO" id="form" acceptCharset="utf-8">
        <input type="hidden" name="board" value="${boardId}">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label> <spring:message code="job.form.client"/> </label>
            <form:input path="client" cssClass="form-control"/>
            <form:errors path="client"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label> <spring:message code="job.form.priority"/> </label>
            <form:select path="priority" cssClass="form-control">
                <form:option value="" label=""/>
                <form:options items="${priorities}"/>
            </form:select>
            <form:errors path="priority"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label> <spring:message code="job.form.status"/> </label>
            <form:select path="status" cssClass="form-control">
                <form:option value="" label=""/>
                <form:options items="${statuses}"/>
            </form:select>
            <form:errors path="status"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label> <spring:message code="job.form.responsible"/> </label>
            <form:select path="responsible" cssClass="form-control">
                <form:option value="" label=""/>
                <form:options items="${boardHelper.getBoardUsers(boardId)}"/>
            </form:select>
            <form:errors path="responsible"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label> <spring:message code="job.form.description"/> </label>
            <form:textarea path="description" cssClass="form-control" rows="5"/>
            <form:errors path="description"/>
        </div>
    </form:form>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" form="form">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
                    <spring:message code="Save"/>
                </button>
            </div>
            <c:if test="${not empty jobId}">
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <form action="${spring:mvcUrl('JC#deleteJob').arg(0,jobId).build()}" method="post">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            <spring:message code="Delete"/>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </c:if>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</jsp:attribute>
</tags:template>
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you mean by: "Everytime I save something to the database the encoding breaks, but for reading is ok"?

Comment: I have a form to add an book to the db. If I save through this form the encoding breaks but when I go to the db and manually change the string, the page shows normally the characters like á é ã õ.

Comment: Have you ever printed the submitted strings before putting them into the database? - is this string still correct or already broken?

Comment: I've tested here, and the string is broke before I save to the database. It might be a problem with my form.

Comment: Check the HttpRequest encoding header, then check the encoding of the html form that was send to the client.

Comment: Well the header generated is using utf-8   Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8